# Using su with service account for management

Tags: linux, unix

We're going through the arduous process of configuring sudoers for least privilege. We were going over what was needed in a meeting and our manager recommended that rather than use our own account with sudo, we `su <serviceaccount>` for the service being managed. This seemed a little strange to me, and potentially harder to administer. I have only been using linux for a few years and my manager has been working with unix for 15+ years so I wasn't going to contradict without some research.

I haven't found any literature about this way of working, however my manager did mention something about problems with restarting services and the logged on user then owning the process. I'm wondering if this is a holdover from a time before service management utilities existed. Everything we use would be managed by systemd so I wouldn't expect this to be an issue. I would also expect if there were a situation where the command must be run as the service account this would be done with `Runas_Alias`.

In the current context of 2020 is there validity to using su with service accounts rather than granting access to our own accounts using sudoers?

*** Additional info for clarification

I'm sorry if I was unclear. The services would be run with a service manager like systemd. This would have the service account specified in the unit file. Running `sudo systemctl start` would launch the process under the account specified in the unit file.

I would expect the best way to administer the system via ssh with least privilege would be to have the commands I need to run as root specified with *my* user account in sudoers. File edits would be handled using sudoedit.

My manager seemed to be suggesting that rather than adding the commands in the sudoers file with my user that all necessary access should be granted to the service account and we should use `su` to do run as the service account to perform these tasks.

This doesn't make sense to me. It seems like it would be harder to manage, grant more access to the service account than it needs, and be more difficult to audit.

Comment: Just to be sure, this is for running systemd services, yes? If so, you'll have to become root or use sudo to stop and start them. If these are services that you've created and you want them to run as a certain user, then you can just add `User=user` to the service file.

Comment: Then he's correct. There's is no reason to put the service account in the sudoers file. All that's needed is for the service account to be able to run the commands in the service file and to have the necessary ownership of any files and directories that need to be read or modified.

Answer (score 0):

There is many reasons for his suggestion, one of the issues you will encounter when running a service with your own account are :

1- The service that is running by a service account loads the environment variables of that account knowing that most services needs those environment variables, they will be not accessible using your user account.

2- When you launch a service with your account, the new files created by this service will be owned by your user. Now imagine the service stopped and someone from your team mates try to re-launch it, once running the service it will try to access the files created recently, but it will be not possible these files are owned by your user account.

3- Another scenario, You launch the service  with your account and one of your team members try to stop / pause it for some reason, it will be not possible also due to lack of permissions.